# Convert literals containing spaces into strings in R

Tags: r

I can use `deparse` and `substitute` to converte any literal expression into a string. For example:

```
f <- function(...) deparse(substitute(...))
f(abc)
# "abc"
```

If the argument contains a space, I can use the backtick operator. Without the backticks, I get an error:

```
f(`abc def`)
# "abc def"
f(abc def)
# Error: unexpected symbol in "f(abc def"
```

Is it ever possible to make `f(abc def)` work in R? Or does it violate some basic R syntax rules?

Comment: It violates the rules of R parsing. It will never work. Something like `f(^)` will also never work. I needs to be valid R syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer.

Comment: I now abandon hope.

Answer (score 0):

`abc def` is not valid R syntax but a non-syntactic name can be used by surrounding it with back ticks. That would still allow use of `f` in the case identified:

```
f(`abc def`)
## [1] "abc def"
```

Other workarounds might be to translate dot to space (if you don't otherwise need dot in the input) or translate _ to space or use ~ in place of space and again translate it:

```
chartr(".", " ", f(abc.def))
## [1] "abc def"

chartr("_", " ", f(abc_def))
## [1] "abc def"

gsub(" *~ *", " ", f(abc~def))
## [1] "abc def"
```

Comment: Yes, back ticks are useful. The workarounds do the trick as well. Thanks.